# Combinational Sum but numbers cannot be used multiple times

Tags: javascript, algorithm

We’re given an array of numbers, and a target.
Example, [5, 10, 12, 15, 21, 22, 25, 50 ]. And the target is 30.
What is the best approach to group the numbers in the array such that they:

1. At least add up to the target number or more.
2. The numbers cannot be reused.
3. Each group cannot have more than X amount of numbers.

Using example array above, and target of 30, and X = 3. So no group can have more than 3 numbers in it.

Example output would be:
[5, 25] [10, 22] [12, 15, 21] [50]

Would the best approach be to sort the numbers in the array, and prioritize grouping the smallest number with the largest number?
How would you do this in javascript?

Comment: How would you do it with pen and paper?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @epascarello The only idea I have is to sort the array and take lowest number to highest, however I don't know if there's a more efficient way.

Comment: @AndrewParks If you know of a specific algorithm name, I would love to know what name it is called, so I can research more into that. And no, it's for a side project that i'm working on for a community in an online MMORPG. The numbers in the array represent players power level, and the target number is power level required to beat bosses. And the X is the number of slots in a party.

Comment: @tzztson What else do you think I should elaborate on? Should I add more examples? Code snippets or something?

Comment: Sorting is not enough in most cases

Comment: Do not worry about efficiency. Solve the problem first and then see if you can improve it.

Comment: remove your react and front end flags. This has nothing to do with either of those and you are going to get down voted for using the wrong flags.

Comment: The example makes the problem seem easier than it is. With X=3, it may be necessary to pick 3 numbers for each group: the smallest number, the largest number, and a number from the middle of the array. It's also possible that the array is designed so that there are some pairs that add to the target, and the rest of the numbers need to be grouped in threes. The example in the question is easy because the numbers are large enough that there's no trouble reaching the target. `5, 10, 12` is the only triplet that doesn't reach the target.

Comment: This problem includes https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem as a special case, and so is NP hard. Do you want a correct algorithm that takes exponential time, or an efficient one that is sometimes wrong?

Comment: Here's a more interesting example: `[4,5,6,8,10,11,12,13,15,18,19]` for you to ponder.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside for the "best approach". Recursion is one of the possible approach for this.

Requirements:

1. At least add up to the target number or more.
2. The numbers cannot be reused.
3. Each group cannot have more than X amount of numbers.

```js
const arrayOfNumbers = [5, 10, 12, 15, 21, 22, 25, 50],
targetSum = 30,
maxCombination = 3;

console.log(findCombinations(arrayOfNumbers, targetSum, maxCombination));

function findCombinations(array, target, max) {
  let combinations = [];
  (function recursive(start, current) { //recursive function
    const sum = current.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); //Requirement 2
    if (sum >= target) { //Requirement 1
      combinations.push(current);
      return;
    }
    if (current.length >= max) return; //Requirement 3
    for (let i = start; i < array.length; i++) { //traverse the array
      const next = current.concat([array[i]]);
      recursive(i + 1, next);
    }
  })(0, []);

  return combinations;
}
```